# Lightning Table Not Display Data

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, javascript, controller, lightning-components

I've been wracking my head the whole day at this, I'm very new to Salesforce and trying to create a Lightning Component that displays Contacts and what Commission they've earned.

I'm just not getting any data to display in the table, I'm pretty sure its the component markup that is wrong.

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" controller="CommissionController" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="accountId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="commissions" type="Commission__c[]" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <lightning:card title="Commissions">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Contact Name</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.commissions}" var="commission">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!commission.Commission_Date__c}</td>
                        <td>{!commission.Contact__r.Name}</td>
                        <td>{!commission.Commission_Amount__c}</td>
                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

Controller: CommissionTableCompController

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getCommissions");
        action.setParams({
            accountId: component.get("v.accountId")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.commissions", response.getReturnValue());
            } else {
                console.error(response.getError());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Apex Class: CommissionController

```
public with sharing class CommissionController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Commission__c> getCommissions(Id accountId) {
        return [SELECT Contact__r.Name, Commission_Date__c, Commission_Amount__c FROM Commission__c WHERE Contact__r.AccountId = :accountId ORDER BY Commission_Date__c DESC];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you checking if there is any value returned from the Apex?
Try to log the response console.log(response.getReturnValue());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try a Quick fix, i hope it would work 
In the doInit func. can you replace "**accountId: component.get("v.accountId")**"
to  **accountId: component.get("v.recordId").**

Comment: My friend, youre a lifesaver.  It works now, I'm going to check what the difference is between accountid and recordid now haha

Comment: Cheers @Rad! Glad it works for you. Let me quickly brief the same, you are implementing interface **force:hasRecordId** which will by default create a variable **recordId** for you, and the same variable hold the 18-digit recordID of the account once the component deployed on the record Page .